# Unexpected keyword argument python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keyword

I am passing the correct parameters, but I am still getting the following error:

```
Starting classification 

 Classification running ... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Classify/classifier.py", line 95, in <module>

    train_avg, test_avg, cms = train_model(X, y, "ceps", plot=True)
  File "C:/Classify/classifier.py", line 25, in train_model

    cv = ShuffleSplit(n=len(X), n_iterations=1, test_fraction=0.3, indices=True, random_state=0)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test_fraction'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code is:

```
def train_model(X, Y, name, plot=False):

    labels = np.unique(Y)

    cv = ShuffleSplit(n=len(X), n_iterations=1, test_fraction=0.3, indices=True, random_state=0)

    train_errors = []
    test_errors = []

    scores = []
    pr_scores = defaultdict(list)
    precisions, recalls, thresholds = defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list), defaultdict(list)

    roc_scores = defaultdict(list)
    tprs = defaultdict(list)
    fprs = defaultdict(list)

    clfs = []  # for the median

    cms = []

    for train, test in cv:
        X_train, y_train = X[train], Y[train]
        X_test, y_test = X[test], Y[test]

        clf = LogisticRegression()
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        clfs.append(clf)

        train_score = clf.score(X_train, y_train)
        test_score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
        scores.append(test_score)

        train_errors.append(1 - train_score)
        test_errors.append(1 - test_score)

        y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
        cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
        cms.append(cm)

        for label in labels:
            y_label_test = np.asarray(y_test == label, dtype=int)
            proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
            proba_label = proba[:, label]

            fpr, tpr, roc_thresholds = roc_curve(y_label_test, proba_label)
            roc_scores[label].append(auc(fpr, tpr))
            tprs[label].append(tpr)
            fprs[label].append(fpr)

    if plot:
        for label in labels:
            scores_to_sort = roc_scores[label]
            median = np.argsort(scores_to_sort)[len(scores_to_sort) / 2]
            desc = "%s %s" % (name, genre_list[label])
            plot_roc_curves(roc_scores[label][median], desc, tprs[label][median],fprs[label][median], label='%s vs rest' % genre_list[label])

    all_pr_scores = np.asarray(pr_scores.values()).flatten()
    summary = (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores), np.mean(all_pr_scores), np.std(all_pr_scores))

    #print("%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t%.3f\t" % summary)

    #save the trained model to disk
    joblib.dump(clf, 'saved_model/model_ceps.pkl')

    return np.mean(train_errors), np.mean(test_errors), np.asarray(cms)
```

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn?

Comment: scikit-learn 0.15.2

Comment: think of updating `sklearn` though ... version `0.18.1`was just released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of the parameter `n_iterations`, which is `n_iter` as explained in the [`ShuffleSplit` documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit). Change the parameter name and the error will cease to exist.

You can send the following parameters with `sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit`, given that we use *scikit-learn 0.15*:

```
n
n_iter
test_size
train_size
indices
random_state
n_iterations
```